# First order logic tableaux method

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

So, I have troubles grasping the tableaux method. Could someone please show me how to prove this?

Assumptions: $$(∃X)(s(a)\to p(X)),\qquad  (∃X)(p(X)\to s(A)) $$

Prove using the tableaux method that $$(∃X)(s(a)\leftrightarrow p(X))$$

I know I should get rid of the implications and equivalence, but I am lost after that.

Comment: [How to format your questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: First of all, you have to consider the two premises and the *negation* of the conclusion.

Comment: I know that, but I do not know how to construct the tableaux after that...

Comment: First apply the $\exists$ rule to 1st premise, with parameter $b$ (obviously new) and then the same rule to 2nd premise with parameter $c$ (new).

Answer (score 1):

1) $∃x \ (s(a) \to p(x))$ --- 1st premise

2) $∃x \ (p(x) \to s(a))$ --- 2nd premise

3) $\lnot ∃x \ (s(a) \leftrightarrow p(x))$ --- negation of conclusion

4) $s(a) \to p(b)$ --- from 1)

5) $p(c) \to s(a)$ --- from 2)

6) $\lnot (s(a) \leftrightarrow p(b))$ --- from 3)

7) $\lnot (s(a) \leftrightarrow p(c))$ --- from 3)

Now we have to start unpacking the bi-conditionals:

From 6), left branch:

8) $s(a)$

9) $\lnot p(b)$.

From 6), right branch:

10) $\lnot s(a)$

11) $p(b)$.

*and so on*...